# Parse empty string to int

Tags: java, android

When I parse an empty string from a textview, it says unknown int "" when I already set a conditional if that takes that case. Code as below.

```
else if (naqaBoolean) {
                    int i;
                    int durasiHaidh = 24;
                    int tempohSebenar = 0;
                    for (i = 1; i < 17; i++){
                        TextView tvStatus = findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier("status" + i, "id", MainActivity.this.getPackageName()));
                        TextView tvTempoh = findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier("tempoh" + i, "id", MainActivity.this.getPackageName()));
                        TextView tvMenstruasi = findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier("menstruasi" + i, "id", MainActivity.this.getPackageName()));
                        int hariIni = 0;
                        String text = (String.valueOf(tvTempoh.getText()));
                        if(text == "Seharian"){
                            hariIni = 24;
                        } else if (text == "-"){
                            hariIni = 0;
                        } else if (text == ""){
                            hariIni = 0;
                        } else {
                            hariIni = Integer.parseInt((String) tvTempoh.getText());
                        }

                            tempohSebenar = tempohSebenar + hariIni;
                    }

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), tempohSebenar, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
```

Comment: May be the string is null

Comment: Problem is at                             hariIni = Integer.parseInt((String) tvTempoh.getText());
 the logcat says it's unknown int "" when I already put the text == "" conditional to handle that. Please help

Comment: I've tried if (text == null), it didnt work as well

Comment: _text == "Seharian"_ must be _text.equals("Seharian")_ or _text.equalsIgnorecase("Seharian")_

Comment: Use `text.equals("")`. For more details [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: Thanks. This works. I don't know why we have to use equals rather than using == tho. Thanks alot.

Comment: Well that link answered my question as well. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning you use:

```
String text = (String.valueOf(tvTempoh.getText()));
```

and test that with your `if`s.

Then, in the `else` block, you parse `(String) tvTempoh.getText());` to an `int`.
Instead of that, you should use `Integet.parseInt(text);`

Also, String comparision should not be done with `==`, but with `.equals` because `==` is a reference comparision. It works sometimes if the Strings are cached but you cannot be sure.

It's because `String.valueOf()` is not the same as a cast (`(String)`).